# Dynamic time warping for a long time series signal with a shorter reference time series signal in fastdtw python package

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, signal-processing, dtw

I have the two following time series signals:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.cos(2*np.pi*np.power(3*(np.linspace(1, 1000, 1000))/1000, 2))
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*(9*(np.linspace(1, 399, 399))/400))
```

so `x` and `y` are in shape `(1000,)` and `(399,)`, respectively. I want to do two following dynamic time warping with `fastdtw` python package:

1. `x` is the reference signal (the longer signal):

I want to map `y` into the longer signal shape (`x.shape=(1000,)`). It's done by the following code:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
from fastdtw import fastdtw
distance, path = fastdtw(x, y, dist=euclidean) # x:reference signal
inds = [ind[1] for ind in path]
y_warped = y[inds]
```

in this case, the above code works correctly and maps `y:(399,)` into the `y_warped:(1000,)`.

2. `y` is the reference signal (the shorter signal):

I want to map `x` into the shorter signal shape (`y.shape=(399,)`).

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
from fastdtw import fastdtw
distance, path = fastdtw(y, x, dist=euclidean) # y:reference signal
inds = [ind[1] for ind in path]
x_warped = x[inds]
```

but in this case, I get `x_warped` in the same shape as `x`, but I expect to get `x.shape=(399,)`. How can I warp a longer signal into a shorter signal?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First, I note you are using FastDTW, but "FastDTW is approximate and Generally Slower than the Algorithm it Approximates."

Before you answer the question in code, you need to answer the question semantically.
Consider the following two cases

1. A= CAT and B = CAAAT
   In this case, you can interpolate the time series to the same length
2. C = CAT and B = CATXXXX
   In this case, you need to use open ended DTW [b]

[a]https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.11246
[b] [https://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Emueen/DTW.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and references. But I still don't know how should I map a longer signal to a shorter signal. My question is an implementation question.